# How to make the Switch component do not move until the value changes - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, native

I use the React Native Switch component to allow the user to enable and disable notifications in the app.

If the user has the notifications turned off in the mobile settings and clicks on the Switch native component, the Switch component makes a strange effect because when the modal appears for the user to go to the mobile settings and accept the modifications, the switch goes to the right and then to the left quickly.

What I want is that when the user clicks the Switch button, the switch does not move. I only want that Switch moves when the value has changed state; or at least delay the visual response.

```
  <Switch
   onValueChange={this.props.toggleNotifications}
   value={ this.props.platformNotificationsActive }
  />
```

Comment: Have you tried using `defaultValue`?

Comment: Can you specify more?

Comment: Use `defaultValue={ this.props.platformNotificationsActive }` and see if that helps. The issue seems to be that the value is e.g. `true` then swapped to `false`. Default value lets you set an initial value.

Comment: It doesn´t work. The issue is that, in the case the value starts with false, the user presses, but due to an error in the process of the call (for example) the value is kept false. But visually, the effect is that the Switch component goes quickly from left to right and from right to left.

Comment: You'd need to provide more code then, there's not enough to go on here.

Comment: I think it's not a problem with the code, because it really works how it should work. What I want can be strange. I want the switch to work but not to respond visually until the value has changed. Just press the switch, the button moves. I want it to move only when the value has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  disabled props
and defaultValue props and change the defaultValue from state using touchable opacity!

disabled={true}
defaultValue={yourState}

Comment: This works - however it makes the switch opacity low on iOS, so technically is not a proper solution.